# What's the equivalent C# method to this basic Java method?

Tags: c#, java, stringbuffer

Really simple question here (more to confirm my thoughts, than anything)...

Java method: [StringBuffer.Delete(start,end)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete(int,%20int));

Java code:

```
sb.delete(sb.length()-2, sb.length());
```

C# (not sure if this is right):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
....
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, sb.Length - (sb.Length - 2));
```

The reason why I'm not sure is in the documentation of the Java delete method. It says

> The substring begins at the specified
> start and extends to the character at
> index end - 1 or to the end of the
> StringBuffer if no such character
> exists

I'm just not too sure about this ***end - 1*** bit of that quote .. and if I might have fraked things up.

cheers :)

edit: Heh. I knew that it was deleting the last 2 chars from the string, but I was keeping the conversion exact, hence my verbose code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the last 2 characters you'd write:

```
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. The "end - 1" means that if you call delete(2, 8) it deletes the characters with index 2 through 7, but not the character with index 8.

So, your code is correct. However some math skills would come in handy here, and you would see that:

```
x - (x - 2)
= x - x + 2
= (x - x) + 2
= 0 + 2
= 2
```

Making the code:

```
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2);
```

Another way of doing the same thing would be:

```
sb.Length -= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the delete call in Java it removes character from start to end-1. The C# call instead removes a string from start for however long you specify.